Llama-3 generated text on Hugging Face dedicated endpoint is garbled mess
I'm calling a dedicated inference endpoint.
In Postman I'm passing the following JSON:
{
  "inputs": "Who is Elon Musk?"
}

But the output is garbled. What am I doing wrong? Is the input not meant to be inputs?
Output:
[
    {
        "generated_text": "Who is Elon Musk?Edited by Kelly Bowen\nDiscover the incredible story of the man behind SpaceX, the Boring Company and Tesla. How did he become a billionaire? And, how did he build from being a self-taught coder in his mother’s house to becoming the most famous entrepreneur on the planet? \n1. Elon Musk, college dropout-turned-billionaireTesla, The Boring Company, and SpaceX about jessicaderosa about rahuldesai about magicboutique\n2."
    }
]

Or
[
    {
        "generated_text": "Who is Elon Musk? Or, as this quiz is framed: ‘Who is Musk?’ For anyone who didn’t know the answer, though, good luck. As brilliant as Musk may be, we wouldn’t say the man is a genius. The quiz posits Musk as the man behind Tesla, SpaceX, Paypal, Hyperloop, SolarCity. Just to name the biggest.\nSomeone else was/is behind PayPal – Jordan River and Jeremy Stoppelman. And the Hyperloop, which hasn’t existed in anything but theoretical form"
    }
]


